# Why won't the scanner prompt me for an input?

Tags: java, loops, console, java.util.scanner

I have this method:

```
public String scanInput()
{
    String input = "";
    Scanner skanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(skanner.hasNextLine()){
        input = skanner.nextLine();
    }
    skanner.close();
    return input;
}
```

The first time this method is run, the program stops, and I'm prompted for an input in the console before it can proceed. However, the second time the method is run, it flashes by without pausing, and my program is stuck in an endless loop.

What line in this method makes the program pause, and why does it only pause the first time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're closing the scanner near the end of the method. That closes the stream it's working on - `System.in` in this case. That means next time you call the method, the stream is still closed, so there are no lines.

You should set up *one* `Scanner`, and pass that into the method (or have it as state within your class).

Comment: Your solution worked, but I don't understand why it didn't work to begin with. Wouldn't I make a new stream the second time I call the method, when I create a new Scanner? I don't understand what is different the second time the method is called.

Comment: @Magnus: No, it doesn't create a new stream every time you access `System.in`. It's *one* stream - the process's standard input stream. If you close it, it's gone.

Comment: Aha! Now I get it. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 4):

The reason your program flashes by without pausing the second time it is run is because `System.in` is closed - closing a `Scanner` object will close the underlying stream.

As Jon has mentioned, the scanner should really be set up outside this function, once, and passed into the method.

To answer your second question - the line that causes the program to pause is the `.nextLine()` call. `nextLine()` is what is known as a "blocking function".

Right now, your code only works one time because `System.in` is essentially the console. You cannot "open" `System.in`. A closed stream **cannot** be reopened.

Yes, you're making a new `Scanner` everytime you call the function - but making a `Scanner` object doesn't make a new stream - the `Scanner` object only takes in a stream as a parameter.

Answer (score -2):

`skanner.hasNextLine()` returns false in this case, because it doesn't read from a file/website etc.